# plist key - UntrustedHostBUID

Tags: swift, xcode

I found this in a .plist.

`<key>UntrustedHostBUID</key>`

I cannot find any Apple documentation and would like to know if this is related to a build ID.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is helpful.

I found this value in `ideviceinfo --simple`  (command from http://www.libimobiledevice.org/ project) when I connected one iOS device to computer. The iOS device refuses to communicate with the computer. The computer has the same 'UntrustedHostBUID' value.

In trusted computer this value is absent with command `ideviceinfo --simple`

Now I try now to remove this, but this is another story :p